# How can I link an item in the chat?

Tags: diablo-iii

If an Axe drops for my Monk and I want to link it to my party or Battle.net chat, how can I do this? Is there a shortcut like Wow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-Click the item in your inventory while having a chat box open, just like in World of Warcraft.

Comment: Too bad that doesn't work for achievements

Comment: I am sure if people nag at Blizzard enough, they will eventually implement it.

Comment: Achievements are already shown to your friends. They simply have to click on the achievement name in the chat to see details.