# How can I link an achievement in the chat?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I achieve something or get some FoS to my friends in my battle.net chat or in my party chat, how can I do this? Is there a shortcut like Wow?

Comment: Related [How can I link an item in the chat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66205/how-can-i-link-an-item-in-the-chat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, achievements are now linkable in chat.

From [Patch 1.05](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7528695/patch-105-now-available-10-16-2012):

> Battle.net
>
> - The "Friend of Friend" feature for finding and adding Real ID friends is now available for Diablo III
> - A new item delivery system has been added that will allow Blizzard to send license-based items directly to players (for example,
>     Collector's Edition rewards)
> - Achievements
>
>   - An Achievement button has been added to the in-game navigation tray
>   - **Players can now link Achievements in chat**

Comment: 404 Page not found. o.O

Comment: @Michel links now work, revised answer with patch