# What's the shortcut in Diablo 3 to show item to a party without dropping it?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I link an item in the chat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66205/how-can-i-link-an-item-in-the-chat)

I saw people show their items to party ingame on stream... I think it's really useful shortcut. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 7):

First, open your inventory, then click in the chat box down the bottom left of the screen (or just press enter). Now you can shift-click any item in your inventory or on your character to link it. Other people can click on this link to see the stats on it.

Also, another more cumbersome way is to use the trade window. Click on a player portrait in your party and select trade. If they're not busy in another menu then a trade window will open where you can both drag and drop items to the window. There you can mouse over them to see the stats on the items.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can.**

The only way I know of right now is to [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66205/how-can-i-link-an-item-in-the-chat/66210) any item in your chat textbox without droppping the item.